# Prolog classification

Tags: prolog, classification, negation

I'm developing a prolog game about finding animal. The user keeps an animal in his/her mind, answer the questions in game and the AI is trying to find the animal.

My problem is about separating the animal classes:

```
mammal    :- verify(gives_milk), !.
bird      :- verify(has_feathers), !.
```

I want to separate this two classes from each other. If the animal is mammal, the AI does not ask "has_feathers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow how you will query whether an animal is a `mammal`: you will need the argument of the animal. So a predicate would look like:

```
mammal(A) :-
    verify(A,gives_milk),
    !.
```

evidently with some kind of database like:

```
verify(cow,gives_milk).
verify(crow,has_feathers).
% ...
```

Next you can use the negation in Prolog `\+` to determine that an animal has no feathers:

```
mammal(A) :-
    verify(A,gives_milk),
    \+ verify(A,has_feathers),
    !.
```

**Do not reuse `bird` and vice versa, because then you create an infinite loop** (unless you allow tabulation support).

## More declarative style

A more declarative style is probably to specify which aspects *should* hold and which *can't* hold. Something like:

```
verifies(A,Pos,Neg) :-
    verify_pos(A,Pos),
    verify_neg(A,Neg).

verify_pos(_,[]).
verify_pos(A,[H|T]) :-
    verify(A,H),
    verify_pos(A,T).

verify_neg(_,[]).
verify_neg(A,[H|T]) :-
    \+ verify(A,H),
    verify_neg(A,T).
```

Now you can for instance state:

```
mammal(A) :-
    verifies(A,[gives_milk],[has_feathers,produces_eggs]).
```

etc.